# Find positions bigger than all their adjecent positions in a NxN matrix

Tags: algorithm

What would be an efficent way to solve the following problem?

Given an NxN matrix of natural numbers, return ALL positions (matrix indexes, i and j) whose number is bigger than all their adjacent positions (horizontal and vertical only, if position is out of the matrix it counts as -1).
In other words, matrix[i][j] has to be bigger than all of the following:

matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i-1][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i][j-1]

If matrix[i][j] fulfilled the condition then (i,j) is a valid position.

Is there any way to solve this without checking every single cell and making all 4 comparisons?

Comment: In theory, every comparison (except at the edges) can be used twice. But the cost of reusing a comparison probably outweighs the benefit (due to the bookkeeping needed to refer back to a previous comparison result). In languages with pointers (e.g. C or C++), using pointers instead of array indexing may speed things up. But that's just micro optimization. It remains that the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: @user3386109 those seem like really small optimitzations, i was looking more towards and efficient algorithm that vastly reduced the time complexity...I gues i ll just have to do it with 2 loops and check every position. Thanks :)

Comment: @user3386109 It gets worse. Any such comparison creates a branch that has the possibility of a pipeline stall. In a high performance language, minimizing logic likely matters more than minimizing comparisons.

Comment: You can look for "singular maxima" in one dimension before ever looking at the other.

Comment: @btilly Wouldn't short-circuiting the comparisons reduce the average number of comparisons to around 2?

Comment: @beaker Actually 1.75 clock cycles, and an average of 2 ifs. But look at http://ithare.com/infographics-operation-costs-in-cpu-clock-cycles/. Comparisons are < 1 clock cycle (yay parallelism!), loads are 3-4 clock cycles, successfully predicted ifs are 1-2 cycles and missed ifs are 10-20 cycles. Adding potentially expensive ifs to avoid cheap comparisons is not obviously a good idea.

Comment: @beaker The best I found is compare with the values before/after, and then compare with values above/below.  Average 2.5 comparisons, 1.5 loads, 0.9375 successfully predicted ifs, 0.3125 failed if predictions.